# laravel 5.6 cookie not set

Tags: laravel, cookies, token

I'm working on a form. When user submit the form, it's failed. I found that the cookie which store the laravel session and token is missing in the browser when working in production version.

However, it's working fine and the cookie is created locally in MAMP version.

I've checked that the output buffering has already been set to 4096 in php.ini file.

I've been struggling this part for a day. Your help is greatly appreciated.

---Update: Below is the session config---

```
<?php

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => true,

    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

    'connection' => null,

    'table' => 'sessions',

    'store' => null,

    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'solutionabc'), '_').'_session'
    ),

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => null,

];
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code, particularly where you're setting the cookie and how you're returning a response. Not sure why you're mucking with output buffering - that should be totally unnecessary to mess with in Laravel.

Comment: @ceejayoz The cookie is being set automatically on MAMP. However, the cookie didn’t appear when I moved the code to the server.

Comment: The cookie related to csrf session does not get created.

Comment: Which server are you using.

Comment: Can you please post your config/session.php file? The issue may be there.

Comment: @CUGreen I have posted the session config above. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @aj3sh I am using AWS : PHP 7.2.4-1+ubuntu16.04.1.

Comment: I see you are using the db driver. I assume you have run your session table migrations on the server?

Comment: @CUGreen Yes, I do. The table is migrated already.

Comment: Is it being populated with session data? check your .env, make sure all you settings are correct.

Comment: @CUGreen Yes, it is populated with session data. But, The cookie related to csrf session does not get created.

Comment: your config looks fine, maybe it is a setting in your .env. Check any session settings in the .env that may be causing the issue.

Comment: @CUGreen Will it be related to php ini setting?

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about that ini setting.